# How to read and fetch data from secpol.msc(local security policy) ---> windows defender firewall with advanced security values in command prompt

Tags: windows-firewall, windows-server-2019, hardening

We are working on `Windows OS hardening` as per `CIS Benchmark` rules .

We are using `Windows server 2019 EC2` Instance.

We want to fetch the data of windows defender firewall with advanced security of local security policy(`secpol.msc`).

We are using below command to fetch the data in command prompt of our EC2 instance:

`netsh advfirewall show allprofiles`

But command prompt is unable to fetch any latest changed data as we are changing values of windows defender firewall with advanced security as per our hardening rules .

Can anyone please suggest us the right command to fetch the updated data of windows defender firewall with advanced security section of local security policy(`secpol.msc`) of windows server 2019 EC2 instance .